# How to use for to iterate inside a String replace every char (A with T, T, with A, G with C, C with G)?

Tags: java, backend

I'm new at coding. And I'm doing an exercise, where I create a random ADN this n length (the one the user inputs). This this, I have to generate a new complementary adn.

The principal ADN uses just = A, C, G, T. In my new complementary ADN, I have to change every char, because 'A' needs to be replaced with 'T',every 'T' needs to be replaced this 'A', every 'G' has to ve replaced with 'C', and every 'C' need to be replaced with 'G'.

Example:

My random ADN would be = ACCGTTTTAAG. My new complementary ADN would be = TGGCAAAATTC.

This is my code where I'm trying to use a for to iterate inside my string and to replace the letters. No success though. But I think I have the idea. How can I proceed?

```
public String cadenaComplementaria(String ADN) {
this.ADN = ADN;
String ADNComplementario = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= ADN.length(); i++) {

    if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='A'){
        this.ADN.replace('A','T');
        ADNComplementario = this.ADN;
    }
    else if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='C'){
        this.ADN.replace('C', 'G');
    }
    else if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='G'){
        this.ADN.replace('G','C');
    }
    else if (this.ADN.charAt(i)=='T'){
        this.ADN.replace('T','A');
    }
return ADNComplementario;
}
```

So I'm trying to use a for to iterate inside my string, I'm trying to read what char is in the position so it can be replaced, it's not working though. I was trying to transfer the ADN value to the ADNComplementario to call it in my main, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

As you can see its a function, I'm learning programming oriented to object.

Comment: the problem you have is that you replace a char but then you replace it again so your string gets scrambled

Comment: The problem is that I can't like, change just one char letters i think. because lets say is ACGT. the new string has to be TGCA. So if i replace first A's with T's, then i have to replace the T's for A's, and it will replace every single T's into A's. Ik it sounds like a riddle...

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong, I'm very confused.

Comment: You should read documentation for replace method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char) there is no need to loop through every character since replace method replaces ALL the characters.

Comment: The way you're trying to do it can work, but why not use a hash map? You can set a rule so instances of a particular char in your string are replace according to a key value (ex: https://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/hashmap-class/replace-method-example/)

Comment: Thank u very much. I haven't seen that topic yet, that's why I did not thought about using it, sorry... But I'll read about it to learn! Thanks again, for the documentation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy!

You just need to use replace method which you used quite well.

```
public String cadenaComplementaria(String adn) {
    return adn.replace("C", "B").replace("G", "C").replace("B", "G")
              .replace("A", "D").replace("T", "A").replace("D", "T");
}
```

In this solution we first replace C with B so that we can replace all the G with C. And then we already know that B used to be C, so we replace B with G.

And we do same thing with A and T using letter D as temporary letter.

Comment: OOOHHH I TRIED IT THAT WAY BUT I DIDNT CHANGED THEM INTO RANDOM LETTERS TO FIX THEM LATER OMG. Genious. Thank u so much!!!!!!! I'm so happy haha. THANK U.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder ADNComplementario = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i <= ADN.length(); i++) {

    if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='A'){
        ADNComplementario.append("T");
    }
    else if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='C'){
        ADNComplementario.append("G");
    }
    else if(this.ADN.charAt(i)=='G'){
        ADNComplementario.append("C");
    }
    else if (this.ADN.charAt(i)=='T'){
        ADNComplementario.append("A");
    }
return ADNComplementario.toString();
```

Comment: Thank u both solutions worked for me! You guys are genious!!! I hope to be like you someday haha. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to convert the string to a char array and iterate through it a replace the chars there. To show you what I'm talking about here it is:

```
public String cadenaComplementaria(String ADN) {
    this.ADN = ADN;
    char[] ADNarr = ADN.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i <= ADN.length(); i++) {
        if (ADNarr[i] == 'A'){
            ADNarr[i] = 'T';
        }
        else if (ADNarr[i] == 'C'){
            ADNarr[i] = 'G';
        }
        else if (ADNarr[i] == 'G'){
            ADNarr[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (ADNarr[i] == 'T'){
            ADNarr[i] = 'A';
        }
    }

    String converted = new String(ADNarr);
    this.ADN = converted;
    return converted;
}
```

This is a great way to replace everything without a problem.

Comment: Hmm lots of sugerences to use arrays, I will get myself into using arrays (or turning strings into arrays) thank u very much for showing me. It's really interesting and it will helo me improve!! Thank u

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Strings are "immutable" which means that after you have created a string you cannot change it. Methods like `replace` return *new strings*.

That means, this line of code does nothing: it creates the new string, and then throws it away.

```
this.ADN.replace('A','T');
```

One of many ways to solve this is by building the DNA sequence using a `char` array. You can then create a String from the array. Example:

```
char[] adnComplementario = new char[ADN.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < ADN.length(); i++) {

    if (ADN.charAt(i)=='A'){
        adnComplementario[i] = 'T';
    }

    if (ADN.charAt(i)=='T'){
        adnComplementario[i] = 'A';
    }

    // add cases for C and G
}

return new String(adnComplementario);
```

Comment: Thank u for your time, I also wanted to try this code and it worked too! I haven't really seen arrays in my classes, but I surely will take this as a reference for new exercises in the future!

Answer (score 0):

try this using a lookup table map (java9):

```
String adn = "ACCGTTTTAAG";
Map<Character, Character> adnComplementLookup = Map.of('A', 'T','T', 'A','G', 'C','C', 'G');
StringBuffer adnComplement = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i < adn.length(); i++) {
    adnComplement.append(adnComplementLookup.get(adn.charAt(i)));
}
System.out.println(adnComplement.toString());
```

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen this yet :O Very interesting, i used it and it worked too. That's the thing I love abour programming, the different ways to find solutions. Thank u!